# Why future example do not work?

Tags: scala, akka, future

I am reading akkaScala documentation, there is an example (p. 171 bottom)

```
// imports added for compilation
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

class Some {
}

object Some {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        // Create a sequence of Futures
        val futures = for (i <- 1 to 1000) yield Future(i * 2)
        val futureSum = Future.fold(futures)(0)(_ + _)
        futureSum foreach println        
    }
}
```

I run it, but nothing happened. I mean that nothing was in console output. What is wrong?

Comment: Nope. It gets printed ` 1001000` in mine.

Comment: How did you run it? I have created maven project and run this code from Intellij Idea.

Comment: On `repl`. Ok, now I get it. You are not waiting for futureSum to complete. And by the time it completes the process is already terminated. So you might want to wait till the future completes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't wait for the future to complete, so you create a race between the program exiting and the futures completing and the side-effect running. On your machine, the future seems to lose the race, on the commenters' who say "it works", the future is winning the race.

You can use Await to block on a future and wait for it to complete. This is something you should only be doing "at the ends of the world", you should very rarely actually be using Await...

```
// imports added for compilation
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._   // for the "1 second" syntax
import scala.concurrent.Await        

class Some {
}

object Some {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        // Create a sequence of Futures
        val futures = for (i <- 1 to 1000) yield Future(i * 2)
        val futureSum = Future.fold(futures)(0)(_ + _)
        // we map instead of foreach, to make sure that the side-effect is part of the future
        // and we "await" for the future to complete (for 1 second)
        Await.result(futureSum map println, 1 second)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, the issue is the race condition where the futures are competing with the program terminating. The JVM has a concept of daemon threads. It waits for non-daemon threads to terminate but not daemon threads. So if you want to wait for threads to complete, use non-daemon threads.

The way threads are created for scala futures is using an implicit `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext`. The one you use (`import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global`) starts daemon threads. However, it is possible to use non-daemon threads. So if you use an ExecutionContext with non-daemon threads, it will wait, which in your case is reasonable behaviour. Naively:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContextExecutor
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

class MyExecutionContext extends ExecutionContext {
  override def execute(runnable:Runnable) = {
    val t = new Thread(runnable)
    t.setDaemon(false)
    t.start()
  }
  override def reportFailure(t:Throwable) = t.printStackTrace
}

object Some {
   implicit lazy val context: ExecutionContext = new MyExecutionContext

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        // Create a sequence of Futures
        val futures = for (i <- 1 to 1000) yield Future(i * 2)
        val futureSum = Future.fold(futures)(0)(_ + _)
        futureSum foreach println        
    }
}
```

Careful with using the above ExecutionContext in production because it doesn't use a thread pool and can create unbounded threads, but the message is: you can control everything about the threads behind Futures through an ExecutionContext. Explore the various scala and akka contexts to find what you need, or if nothing suits, write your own.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the following statement at the end of main function would help your need. As the above answers said, allow the future to complete. Main thread is different from the Future thread, as main completes, it terminates before Future thread.

1. Thread.sleep(500)     //... Simple solution
2. Await.result(futureSum, Duration(500, MILLISECONDS))      //...have to import scala.concurrent.duration._ to use Duration object.